# Code corresponding to leaks with Visual Leak Detector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, detection, visual-leak-detector

I am trying to use Visual Leak Detector in Visual Studio 2008, here is an example of the output I get:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{204} normal block at 0x036C1568, 1920 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 80 08 AB 03 00 01 AB 03 80 F9 AA 03 00 F2 AA 03 
{203} normal block at 0x0372CC68, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <(               > 28 00 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 01 00 18 00 
{202} normal block at 0x0372CC00, 44 bytes long.
 Data: << E             > 3C 16 45 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

The user's guide says to click on any line to jump to the corresponding file/line of code ; I tried clicking on every line but nothing happens! What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Did you compile your code with optimization off and debug information on? Without this, it's unlikely to be able to link the addresses to your actual source code.

It could also be that the leak is occurring in code for which it can't find the source (for example an included library).

Answer (score 2):

You should use deleaker. it must help you.